# Loop Through GeoJSON Properties

Tags: javascript, geojson

I am trying to loop through a specific property from a GeoJSON feature, but having some troubles. Here is how I am trying to achieving it on my local server:

```
$.getJSON('myData.geojson', function(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var obj = data[i];
        console.log(obj.properties[0].ID);
    }
});
```

Here's a small sample of the data:

```
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": 1, "Name": "ABC Cleaner" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 46.879682, -110.362566 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": 2, "Name": "Rapid X Cleaner" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 46.882224, -110.350167] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "ID": 3, "Name": "Ace Cleaner" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 46.885817, -110.338966 ] } } ...
```

For example, if I want to print all the `ID` or `Name` properties, how would I do  that?

Comment: let me know if the answer below is providing you with the correct output @kaoscify

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald — Thanks for your answer. I tried it, but they don't seem to print in the console. They should be printing as soon as the page loads, correct?

Comment: try the new updated code and then if you see the word 'kaoscify' in the console it may need to be changed. let me know @kaoscify

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald — What you did makes sense, but the word 'kaoscify' did not show up. I am basically using `$.getJSON` to put this data on a Google Map using their API, and then would like to loop through the GeoJSON properties. If I do `alert("Hello");`, the alert tag shows up.

Comment: if you put the alert tag in the loop? That is definitely the correct syntax that you need to use, so if the getJSON is successful it will return what you are looking for

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald — If I put `alert` inside the for loop, does not work. If I put `alert` outside of for loop (so second line of `$.getJSON`), alert shows.

Comment: and what if you do ```console.log(data)```?

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald Outside of for loop, it works. So maybe for loop is the problem?

Comment: my guess is that ```data.length``` doesn't mean anything. What does ```console.log(data)``` in the loop give you? @kaoscify

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald In the loop, it does not show up in console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77357/discussion-between-paul-fitzgerald-and-kaoscify).

Comment: if you send me the complete list of data that you expect to be returned then I can tell you what you need to do

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald — Sent to you via our chat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the following code in your loop

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('http://f.cl.ly/items/2k3d2Y3X1m0c3f0l3W3f/sample.json',
    function(data) {
      var result = data.objects.myData.geometries;
      for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        alert(result[i].properties.ID)
      }
    });
})
```

Comment: this is brilliant, thank you for clarifying that we can parse the actual geometries!